# Spring 4 Path Parameter ending in a slash

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I'm trying to get my Spring 4 application to allow Path Parameters that *end* with an escaped slash.

The `@RequestMapping` I've got is:

```
@RequestMapping("/{externalSystemId}/{externalRequestId}/events")
```

And the URL that I'm calling with is `/dummy/ab%2F/events`. So "externalRequestId" is the one that has the trailing encoded slash.

I've gotten to the point where the handler is called correctly, and where escaped slashes in the middle of the path segment work - e.g. `/dummy/ab%2Fcd/events`, but not at the end.

What I've done so far:

- Added system properties to Tomcat:

  - -Dorg.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.ALLOW_BACKSLASH=true
  - -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH=true
- Custom extension of `UrlPathHelper` that replaces `getServletPath` with one that simply returns `request.getRequestURI()`
- Configure the UrlPathHelper with:

  - urlDecode = false
  - removeSemicolonContent = false
- Use this UrlPathHelper from `mvc:path-matching`, within `mvc:annotation-driven`

And I'm at a complete loss as to where to go next. I've even been debugging through both Spring and Tomcat to try and work it out, and I'm stumped. It *looks* like it's because `UrlPathHelper.getPathWithinServletMapping()` is calling `request.getPathInfo()`, and that is returning the path with the %2F stripped out. And that in turn is because somewhere else in Tomcat - I've lost the window now - it has decoded the %2F into a /, then replaced the "//" that is now present with a "/" instead.

This feels like it should be relatively straightforward, so what am I missing?

I've tried it on both Tomcat 7 and Tomcat 8, and with various versions of Spring 4 - currently on 4.3.14.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

The `SlashFriendlyUrlPathHelper` that I had that was the extension of `UrlPathHelper` was causing problems, because my webapp is *not* the Root webapp. Remove that, but keep every other change in place, and it starts to work properly.

Comment: Glad to heard that you found a solution